# Slow file upload SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, file-upload

I have recently started experiencing the behavior in SharePoint 2016 server that the document upload for a specific document library (no matter what size from 10 KB - 3 MB) takes about 5 minutes. Document library was running fine for last 3 years. The behavior occurs for all users (i.e. admins as well). The system stops at the dialog "This should not take too long" and the loading bars.

When I close the upload dialog the document is uploaded and available as expected i.e. it seems that the dialog does not get any feedback/status? Any ideas what the root cause might be?

Different document library on same server works as expected so it should be related to document library?

Found similar issue here: File upload got slow all of sudden on SharePoint 2016

But setting up a document libary isn't really an option at the moment.